# Sending form data via $.post

Tags: jquery, post

I have this code here:

```
$.post('search_results.php', { name: form.name.value },
```

It helps me pass one value from an input field. Now I have a `<select> </select>` and I need to pass it too, I need to pass more variables.

How should I do it?

Something like:

```
$.post('search_results.php', { name: form.name.value , select: form.select.value },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the elements are in one form, the easiest way is to use [`.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$.post('search_results.php', $('#formID').serialize());
```

You can even just select the form control elements you want, for example:

```
$('input[name="name"], select[name="gender"]').serialize()
```

Comment: could you please tell me how to use it n the above way? i realize this is simpler, but until i make it work, it will take em some time

Comment: I don't you know what you mean. Of course you can use `{ name: form.name.value , select: form.select.value }` if you want to, but I assumed you ask for an easier solution, otherwise, why would you ask at all?

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a data object and then perform a loop that gathers up all values and sticks them into the object, then send it to the server.

You can use something like this:

```
var data = {};

$('form *[name]').each(function() {
   data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});

$.post('search_results.php', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

refer jquery serialize() method. you will find examples for how to achieve it

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

you can use serialize() method just above said or if you struggle, you can use key:value pairs,

```
$.post('search_results.php', { ('firstname': form.firstname.value , 'password': form.password.value) }
```